# Hide all panels on asp.net page using JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

There are number of panels on the asp.net page. Panels can be hidden by giving their id in JQuery.

Example:

```
$('#pnlEmployee').hide();
```

Is there any way to hide all the panels in one go without giving their ids?

i.e. They following JQuery can be used to clear all text box contents;

```
$('input[type=text]').val('');
```

Is there any way of doing it for hidding all the panels?

Here is the example HTML code;

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlEmployee" runat="server">
<table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
</table>
</asp:Panel>

<asp:Panel ID="pnlDetails" runat="server">
<table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
</table>
</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: What does the HTML for the panels look like?

Comment: Add a class to them, then `$('.panels').hide()`

Comment: Panels are just DIVs, so iterate through this div for its childrens hiding it.

Comment: asp panel usualy render as `div` so you need specify it, for example set css class

Comment: @jedifans: i have updated the question with the example html code.

Comment: @user1263981 that's not the **rendered** html. That's your webforms code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your panels reveal a common pattern - they all have `pnl` part in their ID. Since panels are rendered as `div`, you can use this fact to build a selector:

```
$("div[id*='pnl']").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try as below:

**JS:**

```
document.getElementById('Panel1').style.display = 'none';
```

**ASP.NET**

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
   <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server">Asp panel content</asp:Label>        
</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: it not working if `panel` inside asp naming container

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understood, you can inspect the Panel element on DevTools and get its ID to bind on JS.

Comment: i mean what if panel inside panel or something like this, it rendered client id not equal id that you setup in design time

Comment: Right, for that just use it: $('#<%= Panel1.ClientID %>')